# Сортировка строк матрицы элементов выбранного столбца

Tags: c#

После того как ввели наименование столбца, все строки должны отсортироваться по возрастанию элементов этого столбца, повторный выбор того же столбца дает, сортировку по убыванию. При равенстве элементов сортируемого столбца, относительный порядок строк не должен меняться, а у меня меняется, как поправить?

Вот пример:

[image: Пример 1]

Реализация моей программы на C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp140
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string current = "";
        string tmpcurrent = "";
        int cp = 0;
        int s = 0;
        int r = 0;
        List<string> nmstl = new List<string>();
        List<string> chert = new List<string>();
        List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
        List<List<int>> tbl = new List<List<int>>();
        List<string> srt = new List<string>();
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            current = Console.ReadLine();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                nmstl = current.Split('|').ToList<string>();
                nmstl.Remove(nmstl[0]);
                nmstl.Remove(nmstl[nmstl.Count - 1]);
                for (int j = 0; j < nmstl.Count; j++)
                {
                    nmstl[j] = nmstl[j].TrimStart(' ');
                }
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                chert = current.Split('|').ToList<string>();
                chert.Remove(chert[0]);
                chert.Remove(chert[chert.Count - 1]);
            }
            if (i > 1)
            {
                tbl.Add(new List<int>());
                tmp = current.Split('|').ToList<string>();
                tmp.Remove(tmp[0]);
                tmp.Remove(tmp[tmp.Count - 1]);
                for (int j = 0; j < tmp.Count; j++)
                {
                    tmp[j] = tmp[j].TrimStart(' ');
                    tbl[i - 2].Add(int.Parse(tmp[j]));
                }
            }
        }
        int o = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        current = Console.ReadLine();
        srt = current.Split(' ').ToList<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < srt.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nmstl.Count; j++)
            {
                if (nmstl[j] == srt[i])
                {
                    if (r % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < tbl.Count - 1; x++)
                        {
                            for (int y = x; y < tbl.Count; y++)
                            {
                                if (tbl[x][j] > tbl[y][j])
                                {
                                    for (int z = 0; z < tbl[y].Count; z++)
                                    {
                                        cp = tbl[x][z];
                                        tbl[x][z] = tbl[y][z];
                                        tbl[y][z] = cp;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < tbl.Count - 1; x++)
                        {
                            for (int y = x; y < tbl.Count; y++)
                            {
                                if (tbl[x][j] < tbl[y][j])
                                {
                                    for (int z = 0; z < tbl[y].Count; z++)
                                    {
                                        cp = tbl[x][z];
                                        tbl[x][z] = tbl[y][z];
                                        tbl[y][z] = cp;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (i < srt.Count - 1)
                    {
                        if (srt[i] == srt[i + 1])
                        {
                            r = r + 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            r = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    for (int e = 0; e < nmstl.Count; e++)
                    {
                        s = chert[e].Length - nmstl[e].Length;
                        Console.Write("|");
                        while (s > 0)
                        {
                            Console.Write(" ");
                            s--;
                        }
                        Console.Write(nmstl[e]);
                    }
                    Console.Write("|");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    for (int e = 0; e < chert.Count; e++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("|" + chert[e]);
                    }
                    Console.Write("|");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    for (int e = 0; e < tbl.Count; e++)
                    {
                        for (int f = 0; f < tbl[e].Count; f++)
                        {
                            s = chert[f].Length - Convert.ToString(tbl[e][f]).Length;
                            Console.Write("|");
                            while (s > 0)
                            {
                                Console.Write(" ");
                                s--;
                            }
                            Console.Write(tbl[e][f]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("|");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

В моей программе, ответ на первый тест я получаю с измененным относительным порядком, вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каким алгоритмом сортируете? Используйте [устойчивую сортировку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: добавьте сравнение начальных индексов в сравнение элементов

Comment: Вот сама сортировка

Comment: for (int x = 0; x < tbl.Count - 1; x++)
                        {
                            for (int y = x; y < tbl.Count; y++)
                            {
                                if (tbl[x][j] < tbl[y][j])
                                { ......